# How do you say "gaming series" in Ukrainian?

Tags: переклад, from-english, non-native-speaker

I have been interested in Ukrainian for quite a while now,having some knowledge of Slavic languages and their grammar. I am attempting to translate a text I made into Ukrainian to begin studying the grammar. And I wanted to play safe here because I know compound words are treated very differently in different Slavic languages,so I decided to ask instead of just assuming via translator ^^

Gaming series,like a franchise. The Super Mario series is a videogaming series. That's what I meant. ^^

Comment: I deleted my previous comments, as your edit made the question clear. But I just want to note that the currently accepted answer was written **before** you revised the question (and therefore it is devoted to translation of "gaming series" as in "gaming series of some hardware", not as "series of games" (the adjective «гральний» can be used to describe something *designed for* games, but not to qualify the word "series" with "of games" meaning)). So, it may be reasonable to re-select an accepted answer (although the currently accepted answer was enhanced with small update too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean series of devices intended for gaming (e.g., *[гральна консоль](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C)*) then you should say *гральна серія* (or *гральний ряд*). [Here](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine66-67-27.pdf) is comparison for two possible adjectives *гральна* (*гральний*) and *ігрова* (*ігровий*):

> ## ГРАЛЬНИЙ — ІГРОВИЙ
>
> Обидва прикметники — *гральний* та *ігровий* — є похідними від слова *гра* й так чи інакше пов’язані з самою грою. Але кожен прикметник має своє коло іменників, з якими сполучається.
>
> У сучасній українській мові слово *гральний* нормативно поєднується з іменниками
>   *автомат, бізнес, карти* й має значення ‘призначений для гри’. Натомість лексема *ігровий* має значення ‘який стосується гри’, тому правильно говорити *ігрова перевага команди, ігровий майданчик*. Прикметник *ігровий* доречний і тоді, коли йдеться про гру акторів, кінематограф, кінофільм (наприклад, *ігровий фільм*).
>
> *Олена Тодор*

The same in English

> ## ГРАЛЬНИЙ — ІГРОВИЙ
>
> Both adjectives — *гральний* and *ігровий* — are derived from word *гра* and one way or another related to game. But each of them has its own set of nouns with which it can be combined.
>
> In today's Ukrainian ward *гральний* is normally combined with nouns *автомат, бізнес, карти* (automate, business, cards)  and has meaning ‘intended for a game’. While *ігровий* has meaning ‘which relates to game’, that's why it is proper to say *ігрова перевага команди, ігровий майданчик* (game advantage of a team, playground). Adjective *ігровий* is appropriate in case of actors' play, cinematograph, film (e.g., *ігровий фільм*).
>
> *Olena Todor*

EDIT: To reflect update to the question i will add that *videogaming series* can be translated as *серія відеоігор*.

Comment: З іншого боку, я не можу сказати, щоб «ігрова серія (ігровий ряд)» було неможливим. В Інтернеті я бачу [122 вживання «ігрової серії»](//www.google.com/search?q=%22ігрова+серія%22&num=100&start=100) проти [3 вживань «гральної серії»](//www.google.com/search?q=%22гральна+серія%22), отже де-факто вираз вживається. Але головне навіть не це, а те, що з визначень слів «ігровий» і «гральний» складається враження, що «ігровий» є просто гіперонімом для «гральний» (справді, якщо _призначений_ для гри, то очевидно, і _стосується_ гри; і СУМ-20 містить приклади «ігровий автомат/майданчик/салон»).

Comment: І [тут](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53382/30956.html) майже явно постулюють вкладеність множин значень: «Ігровий. Який стосується гри; призначений для гри: ігрова перевага, ігровий майданчик, ігрові автомати. Гральний. Призначений для гри: гральні карти».

Comment: @Sasha Мене спантеличує те, що ігровий майданчик і ігровий автомат теж приначені для гри. Бо виходить, що можна і ігрові карти сказати, чи вони відріняються від гральних?

Comment: @Sasha Можливо ти можеш написати свою відповідь? Мені здається, що якщо так широко використовувати ігровий, то не залишиться місця для грального. Мені здається, що якщо приставка призначена для гри, то вона гральна, а ігровою можуть бути ситуація, перевага.

Comment: Формально (якщо забути про традиції / частоту фактичного вжитку) замість «гральний» завжди можна поставити ігровий. А навпаки ні, тому що: (1) якщо щось зараз використовується для гри, то це не означає, що воно для цього призначене; (2) «ігровий» може мати акцент «стосовний _поточної_ гри, а не ігор взагалі», а «гральний» такий акцент втрачає; (3) «ігровий» розуміє поняття гри ширше (акторська гра і таке інше). Але фактично, мені здається, все вирішують традиції і «так склалося» (якщо хтось вживає «ігрові карти» там, де «гральні карти» загальноприняті, то люди відразу починають шукати …

Comment: … незвичні конотації: а чому він так сказав? а може він на увазі не те значення, що спільне у «грального» і «ігрового», а якесь з тих, що притаманні лише ігровому? а, може, він мав на увазі не колоду карт, а мапу (набір мап для настільної рольової гри, наприклад)? Тобто формально, мені здається, значення вкладені, але незвичний вжиток примушує слухачів шукати незвичні конотації.)

Comment: «Можливо ти можеш написати свою відповідь?» Мені знається, це запитання взагалі не про те :). Можливо, автора цікавить щось на зразок «як правильно: „гралн серій“ чи „гральне серія“?», або «„я бачу гральну серію“ чи „я бачу гральної серії“?», «а чому про клавіатуру ви кажете „такого-то призначення“, для серії ігр „така-то серія“, а для телесеріалу „такий-то серіал“?» і т.п.

Comment: «Якщо так широко використовувати ігровий, то не залишиться місця для грального». Мені здається, що вони не взаємовиключні, «гральний» — частковий випадок. Але: (1) можу помилятися; (2) така трактовка справді збільшує ризик виходу точнішого слова з ужитку.

Comment: @Sasha було б легше якби вони були взаємовиключними. Для нас, для мовців, було б легше обрати правильне слово. І слова б не вилітали з ужитку.

Answer (score 6):

The edited question seems to be more clear, so let me suggest another translation:

### серія ігор

---

The literal one-to-one translation does not work every time, especially if it is about a pair of distant languages.

In English phrase, *"gaming series"*, the *"gaming"* is an Adjective, but its role is much more than describing a noun *"series"*. Compare:

- ***what kind of** series? — gaming series*. Here, *gaming* denotes some kind of a attribute of *series*; Just replace *"gam**ing** series"* to *"interest**ing** series"* or  *"bor**ing** series"* to see the contrast.
- *series **of what**? — series of games*. Here, *games* is the key word in the pair. In other words, not just *games*, but a sequence, series of it.

You can also consider an inversion: *seri**al** games*, which seems to be a more specific expression (albeit less used).

In Ukrainian, Adjectives are used primarily to denote the property of a Noun (1st case listed above). So instead of trying to fit an Adjective here, I would prefer a pair of Nouns: **серія ігор**, literally, *series [of] games*`+PLR+GEN`.

Examples are countless. Here's my favorite:

> *Civilization (укр. Цивілізація) — **серія відеоігор** жанру глобальних покрокових стратегій […]* — [Wikipedia](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilization_(%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F))

*Відеоігор* here is a compound Noun *відеогра* (*відео*+*гра*) `+PLR+GEN` (Plural number, Genitive case)

Answer (score 3):

> Gaming series, like a franchise. The Super Mario series is a videogaming series. That's what I meant.

Then the correct answer is ***серія ігор*** (literally: "series of games"). As in:

- *[Assassin's Creed (серія ігор)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin's_Creed_(%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80))*;
- *[Козаки (серія ігор)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_(%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80))* ("The Cossacks (series of games)");
- *[Wolfenstein (серія ігор)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfenstein_(%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%96%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80))*.

*Серія* means "series", *гра* means "game". Plural for *гра* is *ігри* (such style of making a plural form (when beginning of the word changes too) is in general untypical for Ukrainian; but this specific word — *гра* — is derived from its archaic form *ігра*; and modern plural word-form is in fact based on the archaic singular form instead of modern one). To say "of <something>" we usually just put the word in genitive case instead of using any preposition (though sometimes preposition is used too) and genitive case of the word *ігри* (which is plural for *гра*) is *ігор* (full declension table is [here](//uk.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0#.D0.9C.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.84.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D1.96.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.96_.D1.82.D0.B0_.D1.81.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.96_.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.96)).

Additionally ***ігрова серія*** ("game series", "game-related series") can be used. But *ігрова серія* is somewhat ambiguous, as it can mean not only "series of games", but also "game-related series [of something]" (probably it would be more correct in that case to say "series of game-related <something>" — *серія ігрових <чогось>*, but in fact in colloquial Ukrainian speech *ігрова серія* can mean both *серія ігор* and *серія ігрових <чогось>*). But you shouldn't say <s>*гральна серія*</s> for that case ([that answer](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2757) was given before you clarified the question and it tries to translate something like "game-dedicated series [of hardware]").

<sub>Also note that when these word combinations are used in context, you may need to put them into correct grammatical case (only nominative forms are specified above) and grammatical number. In *серія ігор* only the first word will change its form (*ігор* always stays genitive plural), but in *ігрова серія* both words will change.</sub>

```
   Case     │          Singular          │            Plural
Nomenative  │серія ігор / ігрова серія   │серії ігор / ігрові серії
Genitive    │серії ігор / ігрової серії  │серій ігор / ігрових серій
Dative      │серії ігор / ігровій серії  │серіям ігор / ігровим серіям
Accusative  │серію ігор / ігрову серію   │серії ігор / ігрові серії
Instrumental│серією ігор / ігровою серією│серіями ігор / ігровими серіями
Locative    │серії ігор / ігровій серії  │серіях ігор / ігрових серіях
```